# BluetoothLeAdvertiser AdvertiseCallback throws ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have this code to create an Advertise:

```
private void startLeAdvertise() {
        AdvertiseSettings settings = new AdvertiseSettings.Builder()
                .setAdvertiseMode(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                .setTxPowerLevel(AdvertiseSettings.ADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH)
                .setConnectable(true)
                .setTimeout(ADVERTISE_TIMEOUT)
                .build();

        AdvertiseData data = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(BEACON_SERVICE)))
                .build();

        mAdvertiseCallback = new AdvertiseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                super.onStartSuccess(settingsInEffect);
                Log.i(TAG, "======= onStartSuccess:");
                Log.i(TAG, settingsInEffect.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                super.onStartFailure(errorCode);
                String description = "";
                if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED) {
                    description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED";
                } else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS) {
                    description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS";
                } else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED) {
                    description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_ALREADY_STARTED";
                } else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE) {
                    description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_DATA_TOO_LARGE";
                } else if (errorCode == AdvertiseCallback.ADVERTISE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
                    description = "ADVERTISE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR";
                } else {
                    description = "unknown";
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "error: " + description);
            }
        };
        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();
        mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(settings, data, mAdvertiseCallback);
}
```

No matter what I always get

> ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS

I'm testing with
**One Plus X (ONE E1003)**
- API 5.1.1;
- Oxygen 2.2.0;
- Kernel 3.4.0-pref+;

**Nexus 5**
- API 6.0.1;
- Kernel 3.4.0-g7717f76;

(funny thing, with Nexus I get `isMultipleAdvertisementSupported == false` so it doesn't work either...)

**EDIT** - With this model works just fine:

**Galaxy S6 (SM-G920F)**
- API 5.1.1;
- Kernel 3.10.61-5816106;

My original question was, why I'm always getting `ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS`. Now that I found that it works with S6 but not with Nexus 5 what can I assume? Is it a manufacturer/hardware problem or OS version? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running more tests with other devices I found out that this is the proper way to implement it but it will only work with a few chipsets. More information about this technology here: [Chipsets/Devices supporting Android 5 BLE peripheral mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482611/chipsets-devices-supporting-android-5-ble-peripheral-mode)