# Bluetooth (BLE) bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising throws error code 2 (ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS)

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I have a Samsung SM-G950F which [supports BLE advertising](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html) but after a few advertisements, it starts throwing [error code 2 (ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseCallback.html#ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS) in which the android documentation says "Failed to start advertising because no advertising instance is available." and the only way to make it work again for a while is to restart the device.
Another device, the HTC 10 has a similar issue, it works just fine at the start and eventually it ends up slowly missing say 1 in every ten or 20 transmissions but quickly degrades to sending say 1 in every 50. Finally, the device needs restarting to make the app work again.

My use case is as follows:

1. call bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(...)
2. Call that method for say approximately 100 times every 300ms (works just fine until a certain point)
3. Then at one point the AdvertiseCallback onStartFailure(int errorCode) starts getting called and returns error code 2
4. restart the phone (closing the Bluetooth and turning back or closing the app does not fix the issue)
5. repeat the process

Is this an issue specifically for Samsung S8 device or am I doing something wrong with my implementation? is there a way to clear/reset the advertisers programmatically?

Also, if you are aware of any other devices with a similar issue it would be nice if you could share to help others be aware of them.

**Note:**
the same code works just fine on my Samsung S5 SM-G900F running android 6.0.1

code snippets

```
public void startAdvertising() {
    // making sure that the advertiser object was initialised, it is null if the user opened the app
    // without having the bluetooth enable
    if (bluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
        bluetoothLeAdvertiser = bluetoothChecker.getBluetoothAdapter().getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();

        // if it's still null it means the bluetooth of the device is off
        if (bluetoothLeAdvertiser == null) {
            bluetoothLeAdvertiserWrapperCallback.onBleAdvertiseIsNull();
            return;
        }
    }

    stopAdvertising();
    bluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(advertiseSettings, advertiseData, bleAdvertiseCallback);
}
```

and

```
public void stopAdvertising() {
    isAdvertising = false;
    bluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising(bleAdvertiseCallback);
    bluetoothLeAdvertiserWrapperCallback.onBleAdvertiseStoppedOrTimeout();
}
```

Comment: Do you ever stop the advertising? Or are you always trying to start a new one with others already running?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen ah sorry my bad, I have added some code snippets of how i start the advertising and stop it.

Comment: Do you use the same instance of AdvertiseCallback for BluetoothLeAdvertiser.stopAdvertising that you used in BluetoothLeAdvertiser startAdvertising?

Comment: Try creating object of bluetoothLeAdvertiser's object for every method call by calling stopAdvertising() for old object, hence everytime it will create new instance and for every method call the previously created instance would be freed

Comment: Where do you call `startAdvertising()` and `stopAdvertising?`. I think the problem is you starting and not stopping the advertisement.

Comment: Maybe related, but there was no real solution: [Bluetooth LE advertising fails when started and stopped cyclically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656938/bluetooth-le-advertising-fails-when-started-and-stopped-cyclically). At least there's a link to test code that did work on some devices according to one answerer.

Comment: I changed the code to create a new instance of the bluetoothLeAdvertiser every time I advertise something and that has fixed the issue in the S8. The inconsistency that starts happening in the HTC 10 though is still the same as before. Still, I haven't figured out why that is happening. Thanks for the advice till now, they did help to fix one of the issues :)

Comment: @Programonks did find a solution that works in all cases? I face the same problem with Android Nougat on Galaxy S6.

Answer (score 0):

I found some good link for this problem :

[BluetoothLeAdvertiser throws ADVERTISE_FAILED_TOO_MANY_ADVERTISERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158037/bluetoothleadvertiser-advertisecallback-throws-advertise-failed-too-many-adverti)

[Device Support For Beacon Transmission with Android 5+](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html)

**EDIT**

**Device Support For Beacon Transmission with Android 5+**

The list below identifies the Android device builds that are able to transmit as beacons. The ability to transmit as a beacon requires Bluetooth LE advertisement capability, which may or may not be supported by a device’s firmware. This list was last updated on September 13, 2018 and is based on success/failure reports from the [Locate app for Android.](http://The%20list%20below%20identifies%20the%20Android%20device%20builds%20that%20are%20able%20to%20transmit%20as%20beacons.%20The%20ability%20to%20transmit%20as%20a%20beacon%20requires%20Bluetooth%20LE%20advertisement%20capability,%20which%20may%20or%20may%20not%20be%20supported%20by%20a%20device%E2%80%99s%20firmware.%20This%20list%20was%20last%20updated%20on%20September%2013,%202018%20and%20is%20based%20on%20success/failure%20reports%20from%20the%20Locate%20app%20for%20Android.)

---

```
    _____    _______   ______________    ______________
   | PHone    Model       Android-version     Able to transmit   | 

    Htc 0PCV1   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc 0PJA2   MRA58K  6   YES
    Htc 831C    LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Htc Htc0P3P7    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc_0PCV2   KTU84L  4.4.3   NO
    Htc Htc 10  MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Htc Htc6525LVW  LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Htc Htc Butterfly   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc_Butterfly_s_901s    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Htc Htc_D610x   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc_D626x   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Htc Htc_D816d   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc D820u   MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Htc Htc Desire 526GPLUS dual sim    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc Desire 530  MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Htc Htc Desire 610  KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc Desire 620G dual sim    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc Desire 620  KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Htc Htc Desire 626 dual sim KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Htc Htc Desire 626GPLUS dual sim    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc Desire 626s MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Htc Htc Desire 628 dual sim LMY47D  5.1 YES
    Htc Htc Desire 820 dual sim KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Htc Htc_M10h    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Htc Htc_M8Sx    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Htc Htc_M8x LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Htc Htc_M8x LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Htc Htc_M8x MRA58K  6   NO
    Htc Htc_M9u MRA58K  6   YES
    Htc Htc One 801e    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Htc Htc One A9  MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Htc Htc One KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc HtcONE  KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc One KTU84L  4.4.3   NO
    Htc Htc One LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Htc Htc One_M8 dual sim MRA58K  6   NO
    Htc Htc One_M8  LMY47O.H4   5.1 NO
    Htc Htc One_M8  LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Htc Htc One_M8  LRX22C.H5   5.0.1   NO
    Htc Htc One_M8  MRA58K  6   NO
    Htc Htc One M9  LMY47O  5.1 YES
    Htc Htc One M9  LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Htc Htc One M9  LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Htc Htc One M9  MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Htc Htc One mini    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Htc One X9 dual sim MRA58K  6   YES
    Htc Htc_S9u MRA58K  6   YES
    Htc HTL22   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Htc Nexus 9 LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Htc Nexus 9 LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Htc Nexus 9 LRX21R  5   YES
    Htc Nexus 9 LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Htc Nexus 9 LRX22C  5.0.1   YES
    Htc Nexus 9 N4F26M  7.1.1   YES
    Htc Nexus 9 NMF26F  7.1.1   YES
    Htc Nexus 9 NRD91D  7   YES
    Htc Nexus 9 OPR6.170623.012 8.0.0   YES
    Htc One X   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Huawei  ALE-L21 HuaweiALE-L21   6   NO
    Huawei  BLA-L09 HuaweiBLA-L09S  8.0.0   YES
    Huawei  BTV-DL09    HuaweiBEETHOVEN-DL09    6   NO
    Huawei  Che1-L04    Che1-L04    4.4.4   NO
    Huawei  CHM-U01 HoNOrCHM-U01    4.4.2   NO
    Huawei  CLT-L29 HuaweiCLT-L29   8.1.0   YES
    Huawei  EVA-L09 HuaweiEVA-L09   6   NO
    Huawei  EVA-L09 HuaweiEVA-L09   7   YES
    Huawei  EVA-L19 HuaweiEVA-L19   6   NO
    Huawei  FRD-L09 HuaweiFRD-L09   6   NO
    Huawei  GEM-701L    HuaweiGEM-701L  5   NO
    Huawei  H30-L02 HoNOrH30-L02    4.4.2   NO
    Huawei  H60-L04 HDH60-L04   6   NO
    Huawei  Hol-U19 HuaweiHol-U19   4.4.2   NO
    Huawei  Huawei CUN-L21  HuaweiCUN-L21   5.1 YES
    Huawei  Huawei G6-L11   HuaweiG6-L11    4.3 NO
    Huawei  Huawei G7   HuaweiG7-L03    4.4.4   NO
    Huawei  Huawei GRA-L09  HuaweiGRA-L09   6   NO
    Huawei  Huawei KII-L22  HuaweiKII-L22   5.1.1   YES
    Huawei  Huawei LYO-L21  HuaweiLYO-L21   5.1 YES
    Huawei  Huawei MT7-L09  HuaweiMT7-L09   6   NO
    Huawei  Huawei NXT-L09  HuaweiNXT-L09   6   NO
    Huawei  Huawei NXT-L29  HuaweiNXT-L29   6   NO
    Huawei  Huawei P7-L10   HuaweiP7-L10    4.4.2   NO
    Huawei  Huawei VNS-L21  HuaweiVNS-L21   7   YES
    Huawei  Huawei VNS-L31  HuaweiVNS-L31   6   NO
    Huawei  Huawei VNS-L31  HuaweiVNS-L31   7   YES
    Huawei  Huawei Y360-U61 HuaweiY360-U61  4.4.2   NO
    Huawei  Huawei Y530-U051    HuaweiY530-U051 4.3 NO
    Huawei  HWI-AL00    HuaweiHWI-AL00  8.0.0   YES
    Huawei  KIW-L21 HONORKIW-L21    6.0.1   YES
    Huawei  KIW-L22 HONORKIW-L22    6.0.1   NO
    Huawei  KIW-L22 HONORKIW-L22    6.0.1   YES
    Huawei  KIW-TL00H   HONORKIW-TL00H  5.1.1   YES
    Huawei  KNT-AL10    HuaweiKNT-AL10  6   NO
    Huawei  MHA-L29 HuaweiMHA-L29   8.0.0   YES
    Huawei  NEM-L51 HONORNEM-L51    6   NO
    Huawei  NEM-L51 HONORNEM-L51    7   YES
    Huawei  Nexus 6P    MHC19I  6.0.1   YES
    Huawei  Nexus 6P    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Huawei  Nexus 6P    N4F26I  7.1.1   YES
    Huawei  Nexus 6P    N4F26J  7.1.1   YES
    Huawei  Nexus 6P    N4F26O  7.1.1   YES
    Huawei  Nexus 6P    NMF26F  7.1.1   YES
    Huawei  Nexus 6P    OPM6.171019.030.H1  8.1.0   YES
    Huawei  PLK-L01 HONORPLK-L01    6   NO
    Huawei  STF-L09 HuaweiSTF-L09   8.0.0   YES
    Huawei  T1-701u HuaweiMediaPad  4.4.2   NO
    Huawei  VIE-L09 HuaweiVIE-L09   6   NO
    Huawei  WAS-LX1A    HuaweiWAS-LX1A  8.0.0   YES
    Huawei  WAS-LX1 HuaweiWAS-LX1   8.0.0   YES
    Huawei  WAS-LX2J    HuaweiWAS-LX2J  8.0.0   YES
    Huawei  Y538    HuaweiY538  5.1.1   YES
    Huawei  Y635-L21    HuaweiY635-L21  4.4.4   NO
    Lg  LG-D175f    KOT49I.A1396576484  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D285 KOT49I.A1415153763  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D320 KOT49I.V10a 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D331 KOT49I.A1421911913  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D375AR   KOT49I  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D390n    KTU84P.A1417598230  4.4.4   NO
    Lg  LG-D410 LRX22G.A1455085511  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D415 KOT49I.D41510e  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D618 KOT49I.A1395292854  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D620 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D722 KOT49I  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D722 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D800 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D802 KOT49I.D80220d  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D802 KOT49I.D80220h  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D802 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D802TR   KOT49I.D802TR20c    4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D805 KOT49I  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D838 LRX21Y  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  LG-D850 LRX21Y  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  LG-D851 KVT49L.D85110r  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 KVT49L  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 KVT49L.A1406439589  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 LRX21R  5   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 LRX21R.A1421650137  5   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 LRX21R.A1422018487  5   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 LRX21R.A1424924479  5   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 LRX21R.A1445306351  5   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 LRX21R.A1447064049  5   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D855 MRA58K  6   NO
    Lg  LG-D857 LRX22G  5.0.1   YES
    Lg  LG-D950 KOT49I.D95020g  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-D955 KOT49I.D95520a  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-E980 KOT49I.E98020h  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-E988 KOT49I.E98820c  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F200K    KOT49I.F200K30g 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F220K    KOT49I.F220K20c 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F220K    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F240S    LRX21Y  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  LG-F260S    KOT49I.F260S20f 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F300K    KOT49I.F300K20f 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F310L    KOT49I.F310L20g 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F320K    LRX21Y  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  LG-F320S    LRX21Y  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  LG-F340L    KOT49I.F340L20d 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F400K    MRA58K  6   YES
    Lg  LG-F460K    LRX21Y  5.0.1   YES
    Lg  LG-F460S    KOT49I.F460S10w 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F460S    LRX21Y  5.0.1   YES
    Lg  LG-F500L    LMY47D  5.1 YES
    Lg  LG-F500L    MRA58K  6   YES
    Lg  LG-F540S    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-F540S    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Lg  LG-F800L    NRD90M  7   NO
    Lg  LG-F800L    NRD90M  7   YES
    Lg  LG-F800S    NRD90M  7   YES
    Lg  LG-H440n    LRX21Y  5.0.1   YES
    Lg  LG-H634 LMY47V  5.1.1   YES
    Lg  LG-H735 LMY47V  5.1.1   YES
    Lg  LG-H812 MRA58K  6   YES
    Lg  LG-H815 LMY47D  5.1 YES
    Lg  LG-H815 MRA58K  6   YES
    Lg  LG-H818 MRA58K  6   YES
    Lg  LG-H830 NRD90U  7   YES
    Lg  LG-H850 NRD90U  7   YES
    Lg  LG-H860 MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Lg  LG-H860 NRD90U  7   NO
    Lg  LG-H860 NRD90U  7   YES
    Lg  LG-H910 NRD90M  7   YES
    Lg  LG-H931 N2G47H  7.1.2   YES
    Lg  LG-H960 LMY47V  5.1.1   YES
    Lg  LG-K220 MXB48T  6.0.1   YES
    Lg  LG-K371 MRA58K  6   YES
    Lg  LGL22   KOT49I.LGL2220d 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LGL31L  KOT49I.L31L10d  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LGL44VL LMY47V  5.1.1   YES
    Lg  LGLS990 LRX21Y  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  LGLS990 LRX21Y  5.0.1   YES
    Lg  LGLS992 NRD90U  7   YES
    Lg  LGMS330 LMY47V  5.1.1   YES
    Lg  LGMS631 MRA58K  6   YES
    Lg  LG-Q710AL   O11019  8.1.0   YES
    Lg  LG-V410 KOT49I.V41010d  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-V490 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  LG-V495 MRA58K  6   NO
    Lg  LG-V500 KOT49I.V50020d  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-V500 KOT49I.V50020f  4.4.2   NO
    Lg  LG-V700 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  Nexus 4 JWR66Y  4.3 NO
    Lg  Nexus 4 KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Lg  Nexus 4 LMY47V  5.1.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 4 LMY48T  5.1.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 4 LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 4 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 CAF NMF26V  7.1.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 KTU84Q  4.4.4   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 LMY47D  5.1 NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 LMY47I  5.1 NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 LPX13D  5   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 LRX21O  5   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 LRX22C  5.0.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5 LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 M4B30X  6.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 M4B30Z  6.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 MOB30M  6.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 MOB30Y  6.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 MOB31E  6.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 MPZ44Q  M   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 MRA58N  6   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 N4F26M  7.1.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5 NJH47F  7.1.2   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    MDB08L  6   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    MOB31K  6.0.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    MTC19Z  6.0.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    MTC20F  6.0.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    MTC20K  6.0.1   NO
    Lg  Nexus 5X    MTC20K  6.0.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    N4F26I  7.1.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    N4F26O  7.1.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    N5D91L  7   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    N6F26Q  7.1.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    NBD90W  7   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    NMF26F  7.1.1   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    NPG05D  7.1.2   YES
    Lg  Nexus 5X    NRD90R  7   YES
    Lg  VS980 4G    KOT49I.VS98027A 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  VS980 4G    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Lg  VS985 4G    KVT49L.VS98511C 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  VS985 4G    KVT49L.VS98512B 4.4.2   NO
    Lg  VS985 4G    MRA58K  6   NO
    Lg  VS988   OPR1.170623.032 8.0.0   NO
    Samsung AOSP on Galaxy Nexus    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung Galaxy Nexus    LMY49J  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I8190    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I8190    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9060C   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I9060I   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I9060M   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I9082    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9100    KTU84Q  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I9100    KVT49L  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9192    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9195    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9195    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9300    JSS15J  4.3 NO
    Samsung GT-I9300    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I9300    KTU84Q  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I9300    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9300    NMF26Q  7.1.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9301I   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9305    JSS15J  4.3 NO
    Samsung GT-I9305    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-I9305    MOB31E  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9305    MOB31K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9500    JSS15J  4.3 NO
    Samsung GT-I9500    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9500    LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9505G   LRX21P.S012 5   NO
    Samsung GT-I9505G   LRX22C.S012.uNOfficial  5.0.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9505    JLS36I  4.3.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9505    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9505    KVT49L  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9505    LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9506    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-I9506    NMF26V  7.1.1   NO
    Samsung GT-I9515    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-N5100    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-N5110    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-N7100    JSS15J  4.3 NO
    Samsung GT-N7100    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-N7105    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-N7105    MOB30Z  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung GT-N8000    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung GT-P3100    KTU84Q  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung GT-P5210    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung Nexus 10    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung Nexus 10    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SGH-I317    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SGH-I337    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SGH-I337    LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G850A    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G890A    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G891A    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G900A    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G900A    LRX21T  5   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G900A    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G900A    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G920A    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G928A    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G930A    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G935A    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-G935A    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-J120A    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-J320A    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-J320AZ   MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-J321AZ   MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-N900A    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-N910A    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung Samsung-SM-N920A    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-N920A    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung Samsung-SM-T337A    LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SC-04G  MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SCH-I545    LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Samsung SCH-I605    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SGH-I317M   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SGH-I337M   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SGH-I337M   LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Samsung SGH-I747M   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SGH-T399N   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SGH-T999V   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHV-E210S   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SHV-E250K   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHV-E250L   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHV-E250S   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHV-E300K   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHV-E300K   LRX22C  5.0.1   NO
    Samsung SHV-E300S   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHV-E330K   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHV-E330S   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SHW-M440S   JSS15J  4.3 NO
    Samsung SM-A300F    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-A300FU   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-A300FU   LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-A300FU   MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A310F    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-A310M    LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-A500M    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A510F    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-A510F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A520F    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-A700FD   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-A700H    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A710F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A710K    LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A710K    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A730F    NMF26X  7.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A800F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-A800S    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-C9000    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-E500H    LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-E700H    LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G130BU   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G130HN   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G313H    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G3502L   JLS36C  4.3 NO
    Samsung SM-G355H    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G357FZ   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G360F    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G360H    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G360P    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G361F    LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-G386T1   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G388F    LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-G530H    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G530H    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G531F    LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-G550FY   MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-G550T    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-G570F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G600FY   MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G610F    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-G610F    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-G7102    JLS36C  4.3 NO
    Samsung SM-G7102    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G7102T   JLS36C  4.3 NO
    Samsung SM-G720N0   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G800F    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G800F    LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-G850F    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G850F    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G850M    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G860P    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900FD   MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G900F    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900F    LRX21T  5   NO
    Samsung SM-G900F    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900F    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900F    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G900H    LRX21T  5   NO
    Samsung SM-G900H    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900I    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900I    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900K    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900K    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G900MD   MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G900M    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900M    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900M    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G900P    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G900P    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900S    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900T    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900T    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900V    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G900V    LRX21T  5   YES
    Samsung SM-G900V    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G900W8   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G901F    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-G901F    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G903F    LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G903F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G903W    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920F    LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920F    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G920F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920I    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G920I    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920K    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920L    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920S    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920V    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung SM-G920V    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G920V    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920W8   MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G920X    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G925F    LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G925F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G925F    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-G925I    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G925K    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G925L    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G925T    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G925V    LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-G928F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G928G    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G928P    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G930F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G930F    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-G930F    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G930K    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G930T    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G930T    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G930V    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G930W8   MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G935F    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G935F    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-G935F    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G935S    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G935S    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-G935V    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G935W8   MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-G950F    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G950N    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G950W    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G960U    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G965F    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G965N    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-G965U    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-J100VPP  LMY48B  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-J105B    LMY47V  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J106H    MMB29Q  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J110F    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-J110H    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-J111F    LMY47V  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J200G    LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J200H    LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J327T1   NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-J5007    LMY48B  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-J500F    LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J500F    LMY48B  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-J500FN   LMY48B  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-J500FN   MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-J510F    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-J530S    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-J700F    LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J700F    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J700M    LMY48B  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J701M    NRD90M  7   YES
    Samsung SM-J710F    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-J710MN   MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-N750 LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-N9000Q   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-N9000Q   LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N9005    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-N9005    LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N900K    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-N900 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-N900L    LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N900 LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N900P    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N900S    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-N900S    LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N900T    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-N900T    LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N900U    LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N900V    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-N900V    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N900V    LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N900W8   LRX21V  5   NO
    Samsung SM-N910C    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910C    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-N910C    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910F    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910F    LMY47V  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910F    LRX22C  5.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910F    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910G    MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910H    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910H    MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-N910H    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910K    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910L    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910P    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910P    LRX22C  5.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910S    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910S    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910T    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910T    LRX22C  5.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N910T    NMF26V  7.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-N910U    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N910U    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N915F    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N915FY   KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N915T    KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-N916K    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N916S    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N9208    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N920C    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N920I    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N920T    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N920V    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N930S    MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-N950F    R16NW   8.0.0   YES
    Samsung SM-N960N    M1AJQ   8.1.0   YES
    Samsung SM-P550 MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-P555 MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-P600 LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-P602 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-P605 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-P901 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T116IR   LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-T211 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T217S    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T230NU   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T231 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T235Y    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T280 LMY47V  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-T285 LMY47V  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-T310 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T311 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T320 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T331 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T365 LMY47X  5.1.1   NO
    Samsung SM-T520 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T530 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T530NU   LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T531 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T535 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T560 KTU84P  4.4.4   NO
    Samsung SM-T560NU   NMF26X  7.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-T585 MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-T677V    LMY47X  5.1.1   YES
    Samsung SM-T700 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T710 MMB29K  6.0.1   NO
    Samsung SM-T710 MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-T800 KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T800 LRX22G  5.0.2   YES
    Samsung SM-T800 MMB29K  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SM-T805Y    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SM-T819 MMB29M  6.0.1   YES
    Samsung SPH-L710    JSS15J  4.3 NO
    Samsung SPH-L710T   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SPH-L720    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Samsung SPH-L720    LRX22G  5.0.2   NO
    Samsung SPH-L900    KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Sony    501SO   32.1.D.0.386    6   NO
    Sony    501SO   32.1.D.0.386    6   YES
    Sony    601SO   39.0.D.1.25 6.0.1   YES
    Sony    C1905   15.4.A.1.9  4.3 NO
    Sony    C2004   15.5.A.1.5  4.3 NO
    Sony    C5303   12.1.A.1.205    4.3 NO
    Sony    C5502   10.6.A.0.454    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    C6502   10.4.1.B.0.101  4.3 NO
    Sony    C6602   10.5.1.A.0.283  4.4.4   NO
    Sony    C6603   10.5.1.A.0.283  4.4.4   NO
    Sony    C6603   10.5.1.A.0.292  4.4.4   NO
    Sony    C6603   10.6.A.0.454    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    C6802   KOT49H  4.4.2   NO
    Sony    C6833   14.6.A.1.236    5.1.1   NO
    Sony    C6902   14.4.A.0.157    4.4.4   NO
    Sony    C6902   14.6.A.1.236    5.1.1   NO
    Sony    C6903   14.4.A.0.157    4.4.4   NO
    Sony    C6903   14.6.A.1.216    5.1.1   NO
    Sony    C6903   14.6.A.1.236    5.1.1   NO
    Sony    C6906   14.4.A.0.108    4.4.4   NO
    Sony    C6906   14.6.A.1.236    5.1.1   NO
    Sony    D2005   20.1.A.2.13 4.4.2   NO
    Sony    D2105   20.1.B.2.15 4.4.2   NO
    Sony    D2105   20.1.B.2.29 4.4.2   NO
    Sony    D2303   18.3.1.C.1.13   4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D2502   19.3.A.0.472    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    D5322   19.3.A.0.470    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    D5322   19.3.A.0.472    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    D5503   14.4.A.0.157    4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D5503   14.6.A.1.236    5.1.1   NO
    Sony    D5803   23.0.1.A.5.77   4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D5803   23.1.A.0.690    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    D5803   23.1.A.1.28 5.0.2   NO
    Sony    D5803   23.5.A.1.291    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    D6503   23.0.1.A.0.167  4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D6503   23.0.1.A.3.12   4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D6503   23.1.A.0.726    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    D6503   23.1.A.1.28 5.0.2   NO
    Sony    D6503   23.5.A.1.291    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    D6603   23.0.A.2.93 4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D6653   23.0.1.A.1.49   4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D6653   23.0.1.A.5.77   4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D6653   23.0.A.2.93 4.4.4   NO
    Sony    D6653   23.5.A.0.575    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E2006   25.0.A.2.31 4.4.4   NO
    Sony    E2105   24.0.A.1.34 4.4.4   NO
    Sony    E2303   26.1.A.1.100    5   YES
    Sony    E2303   26.3.A.0.131    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E2363   26.1.B.3.109    5   YES
    Sony    E5603   30.2.A.0.100    6   YES
    Sony    E5603   30.2.A.1.21 6   YES
    Sony    E5823   32.2.A.0.305    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E5823   32.2.A.5.11 6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E6653   32.2.A.0.253    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E6653   32.2.A.0.305    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E6653   32.2.A.5.11 6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E6683   32.2.A.0.305    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    E6853   32.1.A.1.163    6   YES
    Sony    F5121   34.0.A.2.301    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    F5121   34.2.A.0.292    7   NO
    Sony    F5121   34.2.A.0.292    7   YES
    Sony    F5321   34.1.A.0.298    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    F8132   39.2.A.0.374    7   NO
    Sony    F8132   39.2.A.0.374    7   YES
    Sony    F8331   41.3.A.2.171    8.0.0   YES
    Sony    G3212   48.1.A.2.50 8.0.0   YES
    Sony    H4233   50.1.A.10.40    8.0.0   YES
    Sony    SGP312  10.6.A.0.454    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    SGP321  10.6.A.0.454    5.0.2   NO
    Sony    SGP511  23.0.1.A.0.167  4.4.4   NO
    Sony    SGP512  23.0.1.A.4.30   4.4.4   NO
    Sony    SGP621  23.5.A.1.291    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    SO-01G  23.0.B.1.13 4.4.4   NO
    Sony    SO-01G  23.0.B.1.38 4.4.4   NO
    Sony    SO-01H  32.1.F.1.75 6   YES
    Sony    SO-02E  10.5.1.B.0.68   4.4.2   NO
    Sony    SO-02F  14.3.B.0.310    4.4.2   NO
    Sony    SO-02G  23.0.B.1.59 4.4.4   NO
    Sony    SO-02G  23.5.B.0.368    6.0.1   YES
    Sony    SO-02J  34.1.B.2.32 6.0.1   YES
    Sony    SO-03G  32.1.E.1.71 6   YES
    Sony    SOL25   17.1.1.C.1.64   4.4.2   NO
    Sony    SOV31   28.0.D.5.9  5.0.2   YES
```

I limit list to Sony Samsung Htc and Lg because of character limit. You can see this link for [list](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html) completed

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Comment: The OP's Samsung and HTC phones seems to support advertising as they work okay for a while and only start malfunctioning later. In fact, the OP linked to the exactly same list of known supported/unsupported list of devices already in the initial revision of the question and stated that the Samsung does support BLE advertising. :)