# Smartwatches supporting Android 5 BLE peripheral mode

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wear-os, bluetooth-peripheral

Which Android wear smartwatches return true for the following check:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();
```

?

On stackoverflow ([Chipsets/Devices supporting Android 5 BLE peripheral mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482611/chipsets-devices-supporting-android-5-ble-peripheral-mode)) there is only a list for Android smartphones and tablets.

Edit: The ASUS ZenWatch 2 returns false.

Comment: I get: sony smartwatch 3 false, moto 360 sport false. it's not looking good.

Answer (score 0):

I read about this [article](http://www.ibtimes.com/what-ble-how-bluetooth-low-energy-android-43-could-revolutionize-smartwatch-1328743) which mentions that Pebble smartwatch contains the sensor for BLE, but the standard has not yet caught on with developers and I also haven't actually checked if it returns `true` on:

`BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isMultipleAdvertisementSupported();`

It is, however, mentioned in [Android Wireless and Connectivity](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#Wireless) that

> Android 4.3 introduced platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy (Bluetooth LE) in the central role. In Android 5.0, an Android device can now act as a Bluetooth LE peripheral device.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The Pebble isn't an Android wear smartwatch. Since Android 5.0, there are functionality in the API to use a device as Bluetooth LE peripheral device, but not every device supports this.