# Devices supporting Android BLE peripheral mode

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-peripheral

An update to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482611/chipsets-devices-supporting-android-5-ble-peripheral-mode) article, since many of the devices referred to in that article are no longer available ...

Is there any way to determine, without purchasing a tablet, whether it supports BLE peripheral mode?

The "[Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/beacon-transmitter-devices.html)" hasn't been updated in 18 months, so it's rapidly becoming obsolete.

Comment: did you find an update yourself yet? I'm interested in a list too