# Android Developement: Bluetooth Low Emission Advertisement is "Not Supported" on compatible devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, beacon

I am working on a android app, which requires me to send bluetooth low emission advertisement with the device on which my app is running.
I read this in a blog post " You need to set the minimum SDK version to 21 in your build.gradle file, as Bluetooth LE advertising was not introduced on Android until the release of Lollipop.". The blog was "https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426.

However, when I went and checked out the Google Repository for bluetooth advertisement, the Minimum SDK was 25. I am confused now. The basic requirement for BLE is that you need a bluetooth device which supports version 4.X. And almost all devices having SDK 21 have that.

Any reason why my mobile(One plus 1), which has SDK 23(which supports bluetooth advertisement) and has a bluetooth chip -v 4.1 , is not able to advertise bluetooth data.

Here is the link to the google repository that I used.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothAdvertisements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the reference link

[Chipsets/Devices supporting Android 5 BLE peripheral mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482611/chipsets-devices-supporting-android-5-ble-peripheral-mode)

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link