# Communcation between devices using only BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to connect two android phone only via BLE. Is it possible? because as per my understanding using Android API I can only connect with BLE enabled devices like smartwatches headphones etc. If I run `startLescan()` method it only shows my fitness band and headphone. 
It does not show other android phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes its possible. As the hardware equally supports to act as a master or slave, but it depends on whether the OS has provide you the required interface to make a device act as master as well as slave. THe BLE in android phone is equally capabale of becoming a master or peripherical but it depends on whehter android has exposed some interface to make it work ortherwise if not you have to root/reflash your device and make changes at OS level.

Yes, two BLE devices can communicate and has been ever since the original 4.0 release.
The change in 4.1 states that a single device can act as both a master and as a slave simultaneously to two different devices. Once device has to act as periphiral and other as master.

See this: http://www.blemobileapps.com/ble-mobile/

For android this link might be helpful for you: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-advertise-android-as-a-bluetooth-le-peripheral--cms-25426

Reference: [Chipsets/Devices supporting Android 5 BLE peripheral mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482611/chipsets-devices-supporting-android-5-ble-peripheral-mode)

Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect to Android phone with BLE.

One of the phones has to be a BLE Server and must advertise itself 
(a role usually performed by devices like smartwatches and headphones) to be discovered by the other phone.

To advertise itself the app uses the [BluetoothLeAdvertiser](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser) class.

Such API was added starting from level 21 Lollipop so your server phone should be at least a 5.0 Android device.

Personally I found [this tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-1/) by Andrew Lunsford very useful for understanding how to realize such functionality.